# angularJs , $http woocommercce set default param

Tags: javascript, angularjs, wordpress

i learn about js and angularjs , and for test my knowledge i'm try to get data from woocommerce(wordpress) , so i find api reernce:
https://woothemes.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?shell#authentication-over-https

```
curl https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v1/products \
    -u consumer_key:consumer_secret
```

code:

```
myApp.controller('homeCtrl',['$scope','$http',function($scope,$http){

    console.log('App Start')
    var secretKey = {
        consumer_key: 'ck_bc51576e596ae1fbf535f8a3d60b281541407006',
        consumer_secret: 'cs_44beee13f3eef60a9d5fb66142fc40a3ba1d2989'

    }

    $http({ method: 'GET',
       url:'https://www.ng-il.com/shop/wp-json/wc/v1/products',
       params: secretKey
    }).then(function(res){
        console.log(res)
    })

}]);
```

it work fine , my questions :

1)how i can set this params for all requests (angularJs)?

2)in js(no AngularJs) to pass paramters is only by var.send(params) ?

3)this is the way i need to pass counsumer_key&consumer_secret?

or have other way?

thank for all!

Comment: can you be more specific about the second question ? how do y ou get the ounsumer_key&consumer_secret ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pass those parameters to all your requests, you can use [interceptors](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) :

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.config(function ($httpProvider) {
     $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function ($q) {
         return {
             'request': function (config) {
                 config.params = {
                    consumer_key: 'ck_bc51576e596ae1fbf535f8a3d60b281541407006',
                    consumer_secret: 'cs_44beee13f3eef60a9d5fb66142fc40a3ba1d2989'
                 };
                 return config;
             }

         }
     });
 });
```

Comment: thank you ! some can answer about the other question?